# Several applications don't run

Tags: update-manager

After doing a software update, many of my applications (e.g., Spotify, PyCharm, Zoom, Ubuntu Software) no longer work.  When I try to run them, nothing happens.  Running form the terminal gives such as the one below (from running Spotify).  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling applications, but I get a similar error when trying to reinstall using, for example, `sudo snap install zoom-client`.  Other applications seem unaffected (e.g., Google Chrome, TeXworks, Matheamtica).  `golang` seems to be related, but I have not installed that nor can I find it anywhere.  What is going on and can I fix this?

````
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x55a609f23ec2]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0x55a60a46e54c, 0x5)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x74 fp=0xc00025be1d sp=0xc00025bded pc=0x55a609cc47d4
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:401 +0x3e2 fp=0xc00025be4d sp=0xc00025be1d pc=0x55a609cd98e2
runtime: unexpected return pc for github.com/snapcore/snapd/logger.SetLogger called from 0xa609f24256000000
stack: frame={sp:0xc00025be4d, fp:0xc00025be55} stack=[0xc00021c000,0xc00025c000)
000000c00025bd4d:  0000000000000001  0000000000000000 
000000c00025bd5d:  000000c00025bd9d  000055a609cc5367 <runtime.gwrite+167> 
000000c00025bd6d:  0000000000000002  000055a60a46d04b 
000000c00025bd7d:  0000000000000001  000055a600000001 
000000c00025bd8d:  000000c00025be0a  0000000000000003 
000000c00025bd9d:  000000c00025bded  000055a609cc5b8a <runtime.printstring+122> 
000000c00025bdad:  000055a609cc49a9 <runtime.fatalthrow+89>  000000c00025bdbd 
000000c00025bdbd:  000055a609ceeb00 <runtime.fatalthrow.func1+0>  000000c000000180 
000000c00025bdcd:  000055a609cc47d4 <runtime.throw+116>  000000c00025bded 
000000c00025bddd:  000000c00025be0d  000055a609cc47d4 <runtime.throw+116> 
000000c00025bded:  000000c00025bdf5  000055a609ceea70 <runtime.throw.func1+0> 
000000c00025bdfd:  000055a60a46e54c  0000000000000005 
000000c00025be0d:  000000c00025be3d  000055a609cd98e2 <runtime.sigpanic+994> 
000000c00025be1d:  000055a60a46e54c  0000000000000005 
000000c00025be2d:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00025be3d:  000000c00025bea0  000055a609f23ec2 <github.com/snapcore/snapd/logger.SetLogger+162> 
000000c00025be4d: <a609f24256000000 >a60aa01e40000055 
000000c00025be5d:  c00028bbc0000055  0000000017000000 
000000c00025be6d:  a60aa01e40000000  c00028bbc0000055 
000000c00025be7d:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00025be8d:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00025be9d:  c00025bf20000000  a60a452cf8000000 
000000c00025bead:  c00028baf0000055  a60a884560000000 
000000c00025bebd:  c00028bb00000055  c00025bf20000000 
000000c00025becd:  a60a450e8c000000  a60a4803de000055 
000000c00025bedd:  0000000017000055  0000000000000000 
000000c00025beed:  c00025bf10000000  0000000001000000 
000000c00025befd:  0000000001000000  c0002b1840000000 
000000c00025bf0d:  a60a46df0f000000  0000000004000055 
000000c00025bf1d:  c00025bf50000000  a609cd278c000000 
000000c00025bf2d:  a60af5fc00000055  a600000000000055 
000000c00025bf3d:  000000004e000055  0000000050000000 
000000c00025bf4d:  c00025bf58000000 
github.com/snapcore/snapd/logger.SetLogger(0xa60aa01e40000055, 0xc00028bbc0000055)
    /build/snapd-9YKbjz/snapd-2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2/logger/logger.go:120 +0xa2 fp=0xc00025be55 sp=0xc00025be4d pc=0x55a609f23ec2

goroutine 19 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:147 +0x9e
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x24
created by os/signal.init.0
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:29 +0x43```
````

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which?

Comment: yes, I am using 20.04

Comment: I realized everything I was having problems with were in the ~\snap directory.  Uninstalling and reinstalling snapd seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: If you have a solution, post it in the anwser section

Comment: Your output does indeed suggest a problem with snapd. Reinstalling snapd to see if that made a difference was a smart move.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall snapd.

```
sudo apt remove snapd && sudo apt install snapd
```